# How can I make Sinatra simulate a refused connection?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I've been using Sinatra with Rack for simulating external services when running integration tests, and would like to write a test for the case when the server is down. Is it possible to have Sinatra simulate a 'Connection Refused' error without entirely shutting down the server process?

So far I've tried:

- Raising an exception
- Immediately closing the stream, as illustrated [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra#Streaming_Responses), before the method returns or anything:

```
    post '/external_app' do
        stream(:keep_open) do |out|
            out.close
        end
    end
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are your findings after using those two techniques?  What is the problem you still face?

Comment: Raising an exception simply returns a 500 with a stack trace, and I was unable to even enter into the stream body to close it prematurely from following the instructions in the documentation link. From what I've heard, [the `stream` example doesn't work with rack.](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/streaming.html#label-Better+Middleware+Handling) I probably should have mentioned that when I posted this, editing the question now. (The 500 doesn't fit my needs since it's still returning a response.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to test server down, the approach you've done still relies on the response of sinatra server.

you can set a very short connection timeout in your http client (any http client should be able to do that)

And then have something like a `sleep` method in your sinatra action block with `x` seconds that's greater than the max timeout you set.

But actually you may not need to make things that complicate, you can just throw an exception that your http client throw for connection timeout (and any other connection exceptions), and test to see if your application is able to catch and process the exception(s) accordingly.

Comment: The timeout idea works for my use case. Not ideal, since our automated test cases now take quite a while longer, but it definitely is a solution.